# How to use WPML Plugin in contact form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, plugin-wpml

I have using WPML plugin in my website for the purpose of translating the content.

I have a query how to translate the content within the contact form 7 via WPML plugin.

I example : in my contact form have Name, Email, Phone and message fields. So I have set texts before the field (in English). So if clicking the website into another language ( for example , in arabic) , how to change the field identification text such as Name, Email, Phone and Message into Arabic?

Please let me know the solution , if any one have done.
Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you have to set up a new form in you additional language. You can copy paste the existing form and edit the words to be translated

Comment: Instead of WPML, use [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) and [CF7 Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-polylang/) extension plugins to do exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another Contact Form for any different language.

You include the form with shortcode, so it's pretty easy to duplicate a form, translate it to given language and then modify the shortcode.

Comment: Hi @Krzysiek Dróżdż
Thank you for sharing your information.